# why does my line of code seem to ignore calling my function?

Tags: python

I have been working on a shop for a text based game. I have gotten everything to work.....except the end. at the end the program ask the player 'Would that be all?' and whatever you input gets put into a variable called answer. then based on what you put in it is supposed to either return you to the line shop() was called or call shop() again. Here is the code.

```
print('Would that be all?')
answer =input()
if answer ='yes'.startswith('y'):
    return
```

Comment: `if answer.startswith('y'):`

Comment: No it doesn't, that's a syntax error. (You're trying to do assignment in an `if`. Show your actual code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fail your condition (and I add a `lower()` to be case-insensitive ;) ):

```
print('Would that be all?')
answer = input()
if answer.lower().startswith('y'):
    return
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to test if two things are equal, you need to use "==" (the equality comparison symbol), not "=" (the assignment symbol).

Second of all, it looks like you couldn't decide if you were testing if answer equals "yes" or answer starts with "y".  I think you need to pick one:

```
print('Would that be all?')
answer = input()
if answer == 'yes':
    return
```

or

```
print('Would that be all?')
answer = input()
if answer.startswith('y'):
    return
```

Comment: it's pointless to use `or`. `yes` starts with a `y`.

Comment: True enough.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using:

```
if answer.startwith('y'):
```

or

```
if answer == 'yes':
```

or similar.